# how to display images in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I saved the images in the public/images folder.
"/images/profile.jpg" this is how the code for an images looks like. But instead of the image it appears a broken image icon. 
The thing is that I can see one image that I added a week ago but I can't see the others.

Comment: <img src="/images/profile.jpg"> should be work. And please verify the images in public folder.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, right click on the broken icon and do "inspect" - it should tell you where it's trying to serve the image from. Then, check your images folder to make sure the image with the same name is in there.

Comment: i had a problem with case-sensitivity of image names. The image name was Pan.jpg and I referred it to as pan.jpg. I had the broken image link.